# How to make custom categories for every post type in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have custom post types on my page and I need custom categories for each post type. Is it possible to do that? I found this question: [Custom category for custom post type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127594/custom-category-for-custom-post-type) but it creates only **TAGS** I need category checkboxes..

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I found that.. If anyone need it, you have to add to args hierarchical argument.

So for example:

```
function register_book_genre_taxonomy() {
register_taxonomy(
    'book_genre',
    'books',
    array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'label' => __( 'Genre' ),
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'genre' )
    )
);
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_book_genre_taxonomy' );
```